# IIS Appends a forwod slash at the end to the URL during http redirect

Tags: iis, http-redirect

I have a URL which will redirect to a google form.
But Somehow IIS appends a forward slash at the end of the URL and the google form stop working
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdRF-AfkYYC9KdOuz8fWZujc0Uza-FdqHZiD-miQfPhws5hBQ/viewform/

In the above link if you remove the last / it work..
Is there a way we can stop IIS from doing so.
I am using IIS 8.5 on Windows 2012 R2
I have checked in the HTTP redirect option there is no /(forward slash)

Comment: How are you redirecting it?

Comment: I have created a site in IIS and use HTTP Redirect.
Just check the "Redirect Requests to this Destination" checkbox and just give URL to redirect in the text box below..